# Passing user input to a constructor Ruby

Tags: ruby, constructor

I'm attempting to pass the user input as an argument to the constructor, rather than passing it to the one method. When I do, I get the error message "in initialize: wrong number of arguments <1 for 0> " on line 20 (or where the constructor is created). Why won't the constructor take the argument?

```
  class Beginnerbudget
     def rate_savings(amount)
        @amount = amount
        if amount >= 501
            puts "You have $#{amount} in your account. Keep up the good
            work!"
        elsif amount <= 500 && amount >= 101
            puts "You only have $#{amount} in your account. Try and save
            a little more this month."
        else amount < 100
            puts "Yikes, you only have $#{amount} in your account! Sell
            a kidney quick!"
        end
      end
    end

puts "How much money do you have in your checking account?"
amount = gets.chomp.to_i

beginner_budget = Beginnerbudget.new(amount)
beginner_budget.rate_savings`
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost got it. `beginner_budget` should be created first by setting it to a new instance of `Beginnerbudget`. Then, using `beginner_budget`, you can call any method inside `Beginnerbudget` and pass any arguments necessary for the specific method.

```
amount = gets.chomp.to_i

beginner_budget = Beginnerbudget.new
beginner_budget.rate_savings(amount)
```

Just to note, passing an argument to `Beginnerbudget.new(argument)` implies that the argument is meant for an initialize method you have in that class. So this would work for:

```
class Beginnerbudget
  def initialize(name)
    @budget_name = name
  end
  def print_budget(amount)
    puts "#{@name}: #{amount}"
  end
end

some_budget = Beginnerbudget("Gas")
some_budget.print_budget(10)
```

returns `Gas: 10`

Edit:

Also, I recommend removing the following: `@amount = amount`. No need to create an instance variable in this case because you are passing the argument to your method, so scope of the argument is there and works.

Instance variables are great if you want to use a variable in multiple methods in your class. It will extend scope to all methods inside your class.